# RubyMine popups and window events die after successful system resume

Tags: java, sleep

After I resume from sleep, RubyMine must be restarted in order to be functional. Things like opening files, search dialog, panes, etc are all non-responsive.

This may be related to java not rubymine, but that is the manifestation on my system. Using RubyMine 3.1 + Sun JDK.

Possible that firefox is also affected by this in that it begins to eat up cpu like nobody's business after a few sleeps. Could this be an issue with sleep?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but it isn't when resuming from sleep. It just seems to happen randomly.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards